# Science fiction novel that had an authoritarian society with rigid eugenics based on intelligence and artificial blood

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this back in 1992-93.

I'm trying to recall a novel that had an authoritarian society with rigid eugenics based on intelligence. I can't recall a great deal more except that the main male protagonist ends up being displaced by his assistant for breaking the eugenics code and having an affair with a lady with a much lower eugenics grading.

The main character is then forced to donate his body to the artificial blood program he was previously running, with the expected poor consequences for both the protagonist and the dog they were using the artificial blood in.

Comment: Trying to remember what I'm 99% sure is the same book, I read it in 1982 or 1983. The male protagonist had previously disposed of his female boss in a similar way (after having had an affair with her). I think the chapters go up to Z at the point where he takes over the top job (whatever it is) and then start from A. Very dodgy competitive "sports" in a public arena. As I remember, basically a story about "just because you're paranoid doesn't mean they're NOT after you..."

Comment: Thanks indeed @AndyM, that sounds about right. Please do let me know if inspiration strikes, be great to read it again

Comment: Is this term used in the story?.. You don't work for somebody, instead you are 'used' by them

Comment: @DannyMcG apologies but that's I don't recall 'using' as meaning 'employing' being used either way in the book

Comment: I've also recalled recently that the book contained the word 'avoirdupois', from memory in relation to the curves of the woman that the main character was having an affair with. I freely admit that I had to go look the word up, hence recalling it all these years later

Comment: Was "avoirdupois" written like this? This sounds like the French for "being overweight". Did you read this in English, was it a translation, if so from which language? If not, what language was it written in?

Comment: @Jenayah It's primarily a system of weights and measurement, but not common or modern.

Comment: @Jenayah to the very best of my recollection it was written in English and not a translation. There was a sense of avoirdupois being a reference to the female being voluptuous. Caveat - it's nearly 20 years since I read it

Comment: @AndyM can I ask please if you had any luck recalling the book mentioned in your previous post? Thanks indeed

Comment: It's not Mount Dragon by Preston and Child. That was published in 1996, I read this book between 1991 and 1993. I don't think it's anything by Octavia E. Butler, the book was set on a near future Earth rather than anything with aliens or vampires. I've looked at Bloodchild and, despite the great name, I don't think it fits

Comment: @AndyM any luck please recalling any more details on this one? Thanks indeed in advance

Comment: @AndyM any luck please recalling the story you mentioned above?